# GeoServer preventing overwriting html files

Tags: geoserver, boundless-suite

I have GeoServer installed on Windows XP as part of the OpenGeo bundle. It's working well and I have just started creating my own app using it.

I have created an html file in \WebApps\apps and can view it via localhost:8080. My problem is that once I have viewed the file in a browser it becomes locked and I can't save over it.

Has anyone else had this problem? Is there a fix?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have experienced the same with Notepad++. There is no fix that I'm aware of, but a workaround - use plain Notepad, which will still let you write the file. Other text editors may also work, but I haven't tried.

Comment: Interesting. I'm using Notepad++ so that sounds like a likely candidate...

Comment: Yep, I can save in plain old Notepad. How annoying! Thanks!

Comment: Notepad2 to the rescue! - http://www.flos-freeware.ch/notepad2.html

Comment: A definitive answer: http://docs.codehaus.org/display/JETTY/Files+locked+on+Windows

Answer (score 1):

Not a fix for GeoServer, but you can unlock files that are locked by other processes by using [Unlocker](http://unlocker.emptyloop.com/).  Crucial utility to have installed on your system.

Comment: I tried it - it didn't work. Useful piece of software though.

Answer (score 0):

This caught me out for a while and that codehaus link no longer works so for reference (based on the OpenGeo suite install but applicable with any Jetty geoserver setup probably)...

Main one to enable editing and saving html files in root is D:\Apps\OpenGeo\jetty\etc\webdefault.xml
set useFileMappedBuffer to false (was true)

Cheers
Andy